# vue dynamic vlaue based on multiple data

Tags: vue.js, vue-directives, vue-styleguidist

based on most of vue docs that have mentioned to single parameter, 
I used the v-on:mouseover and leave to control  style dynamically based on each item color because i need to change each item color by hover based on its color and although I used `!important` with styles, it doesn't change

```
<li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id">
    <a class="my-link"
        v-on:mouseleave="mouseLeave(item)"
        v-on:mouseover="mouseOver(item)">

        {{ item.title }}
    </a>
</li>

data() {
    return {
        items: [
            {
                id: 1,
                title: "one",
                color: "#ccc"
            },
            {
                id: 2,
                title: "two",
                color: "#000"
            },
            {
                id: 3,
                title: "three",
                color: "#c7c7c7"
            }
        ]
     }
},
methods: {
    mouseOver: function(item){
        this.$el.children[0].style.color = 'red !important';
    },
    mouseLeave: function(item){
        this.$el.children[0].style.color = `${item.color} !important`;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do not mutate the DOM. use vue to bind styles. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html

Comment: as i said i tried all the single data styling, i need to pass different style as color to css or style

Answer (score 2):

Another approach without using mouseleave and mouseover, only CSS:

Apply the main color with **:style** for each list item from its data definition. Also add class on the parent element `class="list"` with the color for hover effect. And finally `class="list-item"` which inherits color from the parent on hover only. Thus color **red** is inherit on hover only:

```
<li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id" class="list" :style="{ color: item.color }">
    <a class="list-item">
        {{ item.title }}
    </a>
</li>
```

```
<style scopped>
.list-item {
  color: red;
}
.list-item:hover {
  color: inherit !important;
}
</style>
```

**Live example:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
       items: [
        {
          id: 1,
          title: "one",
          color: "red",
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          title: "two",
          color: "green",
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          title: "three",
          color: "blue",
        }
      ]},
  template: `
   <div>
    <li v-for="item in items" v-bind:key="item.id" class="list" :style="{ color: item.color }">
      <a class="my-link list-item">
        {{ item.title }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </div>`
})
```

```css
.list-item {
  color: #ccc;
}
.list-item:hover {
  color: inherit !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
```

Comment: thanks for response, but as i mentioned the main issue is the different colors as hover, the initial and basic color is same for example red, but with hover it will change to its color, with your way, all items have same hover color (red)

Comment: You mean that you need different color on each item when hovering on them? For example the main color is red and when hovering on item one it becomes grey, is this ?

Comment: perfect, i moved the `:style="{ color: item.color }"` to `<li> and only used `.list-item:hover {color: inherit !important;}, it was a smart solution

Comment: Yes, I also learned about this trick some time ago with inherit color from parent on hover. For this purpose it works perfectly!